# Phonegap Calendar plugin is asking for calendarName in findAllEventsInNamedCalendar method

Tags: ios, cordova, calendar

I am using calendar plugin to fetch all the events from iOS native calendar.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

I am trying to use the below method for that.

```
var calendarName = "iCal";
window.plugins.calendar.findAllEventsInNamedCalendar(calendarName,success,error);
```

When I am running the application, and trying to fetch all the events, it is showing the below error.

**"Error: could not find calendar."**

```
$("#create").click(function(){
window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,location1,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);
});

$("#find").click(function(){
window.plugins.calendar.findEvent(title,location1,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);
});

$("#deleteAll").click(function(){
window.plugins.calendar.deleteEvent(title,location1,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);
});
```

Create events, find events and Delete is working.

Can any one help to find out what should be the value of "**calendarName**" variable to find the value from iOS native database ?

Answer (score 0):

you are just running full code which is given to github right

first you have to create calendar then you can find it. in below sequence once calendar is created then in second it will be deleted too.

```
// prep some variables
var startDate = new Date("September 24, 2013 13:00:00");
var endDate = new Date("September 24, 2013 14:30:00");
var title = "My nice event";
var location = "Home";
var notes = "Some notes about this event.";
var success = function(message) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(message)); };
var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + message); };
var calendarName = "iCal";

// create a calendar (iOS only for now)
window.plugins.calendar.createCalendar(calendarName,success,error);

// create in a named calendar (iOS only for now)
window.plugins.calendar.createEventInNamedCalendar(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,calendarName,success,error);
```

Now you can check below events

```
// find (iOS only for now)
window.plugins.calendar.findEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,success,error);

// find all events in a named calendar (iOS only for now)
window.plugins.calendar.findAllEventsInNamedCalendar(calendarName,success,error);
```

Comment: Edited my question. Add events, find events and delete events are working fine. and I can see the values also. I am not getting in which  calendar it is showing automatically. At the time of "findAllEventsInNamedCalendar" it is asking for "calendarName" . Which I am not sure. :(

Comment: You can create your own calendarName. It is upon you totally.

Answer (score 0):

the PhoneGap 2.x version does not support the named calendar. Maybe you are using the 2.x version of the plugin with the 3.x readme?
Please refer to the 2.x readme: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/pre-3.0